# Error in reading values when ngModel is conditional

Tags: angular

I am using ngModel for two-way binding (display value in the input box and update the value of the model if user change that) and it was working fine.

```
<input
 id="myInput"
 name="myInput"
 type="text"
 [(ngModel)]="myModel && myModel.myProperty"
 />
```

Code to get data from DB-

```
this.getresponse$ = this.myService.serviceMethodName.subscribe(
        (result: ModelType) => { => {
            this.myModel= result;
        },
        error => {
            console.log(
                'Error while no tring to fetch settings not exists in database.',
            );
        },
    );
```

Now, if the result is null from DB and after bind to controls and the user sets some value in the input box, then I trying to read the value from the model, the model shows undefined.

Comment: This was due to the non-initilization of the 'myModel' object. It worked when I initialize an empty object in constrictor. Thanks for all responses.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to achieve? In the second case, `myModel.myProperty` should still be updated when you either change the value of the input or the value of the model.

See a quick demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wfzh1u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for your response and I update the question now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input 
 type="text"
 #myInput = "ngModel"
 [(ngModel)]="myBindableProperty"
 (ngModelChange)="myBindableProperty = onPropertyChange(myInput)"
 />
```

The triad of ngModel is

- #myInput being set to ngModel. (Angular's own control name syntax)
- The ngModel two way binding syntax: [(ngModel)]
- (ngModelChange) which points to an event handler.

Note that myBindable property is a property in your Typescript file for this component.

ngModelChange always fires first and sends in the myInput PARAM which is the ngModel. Here's what the ngModel contains.

[image: ng model internals]

There are two fields of interest the model (last known value), and the viewmodel (current change). If your onPropertyChange event handler always returns the viewmodel then true two way binding is ready to go.

It's a bit goofy but works every time, plus it gives you the ability to kick of asynchronous work when the change happens.

If you use Pipes they always fire last and do not affect another change cycle.  Here's an article on that https://dev.to/jwp/angular-ngmodel-model-and-viewmodel-5m